# springboot connects to redis pool

Tags: redis, spring-boot

i m building a REST api using springboot and redis. with provided @Autowired StringRedisTemplate, i can easily connect to my local redis. but on production we are using redis pool, so in application.properties file i specified the redis pool:

```
spring.redis.sentinel.master=mymaster,mymaster_02
spring.redis.sentinel.nodes=mel-01:26379,mel-02:26379,mel-03:26379
```

java code:

```
 @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, String> redis;
```

then when i run mvn spring-boot:run, it failed:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool.toHostAndPort(JedisSentinelPool.java:159)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool.initSentinels(JedisSentinelPool.java:122)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool.<init>(JedisSentinelPool.java:73)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool.<init>(JedisSentinelPool.java:49)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.createRedisSentinelPool(JedisConnectionFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.createPool(JedisConnectionFactory.java:180)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet(JedisConnectionFactory.java:173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
```

Update:
digged more into the code and find springboot cannot handle multiple masters:

```
spring.redis.sentinel.master=mymaster,mymaster_02
```

our redis cluster is sharded, 4 nodes total, data split between node 1, 2 and node 3, 4. node 2 is slave of node 1, node 4 is slave of node 3. in our case can spring boot works with redis at all?  thanks!

Comment: Did you find an answer? I am having a similar issue.